# GIMP: I mistakenly clicked "don't ask again" when asked to rotate picture. How to undo this?

Tags: gimp

I imported some pics from my cell phones and although they seem straight on preview GIMP shows them as rotated and when I opened each file it asked me something like:

"Do you want to rotate that image?"

I mistakenly clicked no, not before I hitted "please don't ask again".

How to undo this?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure Gimp is not running
2. Locate your "Gimp profile" (normally `~/.gimp-2.8` if on 2.8, otherwise see [here](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/) for ways to locate it.
3. Edit the `parasiterc` file with a text editor
4. Find a line that starts with `(parasite "exif-orientation-rotate" ...`)
5. Delete the line and save the file.